# Как отправить сообщение и фото через aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Мне нужно отправить одним сообщением текст и скачанную картинку через aiogram. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=photo, caption="text")
```